# Multiple git repositories with 1 main repository

Tags: linux, git

I'm using my own admin panel for multiple websites.

I have a git repository for just the admin panel, and a seperate git repository for every website.

So my question is: How can I update my admin panel easily. When I commit something to the admin panel repository, how can I automatically merge the new feature into the websites that are using that admin panel.

Do I need a plugin on my server for it or can I run some commands on the server every time something gets commited in the admin panel it merges with the other repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

In every repository that depends on the admin panel repository, you should add a submodule. Say repo1 and repo2 depend on the admin panel.

```
 cd repo1/
 git submodule add <admin_panel_repository_url>
```

And that's it. If the admin panel repository has changed, you can update repo1 and repo2:

```
cd repo1/
git submodule update
```

Hope that helps.